# Restlet's GET POST DELETE method route to the same function

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, restlet

This question is very strange.Details as below.

I use restlet with spring/tomcat in a project to provide REST service. But in some cases, All HTTP methods(POST/DELETE/GET) request goes into the same function, such as the `@Get` routine, and sometimes all method request goes into the `@Post` routine. Cases are different every time I restart the tomcat. and sometimes all methods works.

This is my configuration:

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>restlet</servlet-name>

    <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringServerServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.restlet.component</param-name>
        <param-value>component</param-value>
    </init-param>

</servlet>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<bean id="component" class="org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringComponent">
    <property name="defaultTarget" ref="restRouter" />
</bean>
<bean id="restRouter" class="org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringBeanRouter"></bean>
<bean name="/v1.0/{tenant}/templates/{id}" id="one" class="com.XXX.TemplateResource"/>
```

**TemplateResource** extends the ServerResource

```
@Get
@Override
public Representation get(){
    // some code
}
```

I think the configuration is ok, and sometimes everything works. 
So is it something wrong with other thing like eclipe or tomcat? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `applicationContext.xml`

```
<bean name="/v1.0/{tenant}/templates/{id}" id="one" class="com.XXX.TemplateResource"/>
```

For `SpringBeanRouter`, `Resources` must be scoped prototype, since a new instance must be created for each request.

See [SpringBeanRouter API](http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/javadocs/2.2/jse/ext/org/restlet/ext/spring/SpringBeanRouter.html) and [restlet-spring-example](http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.3/extensions/spring/example) for details.

Comment: you mean add `scope="prototype"` in the `Resource` beans. OK, I will try. And thank you for the details documents.